# What is the use of this USB (mini-B) cable that has a forked connection?

Tags: usb, cable

What is the use of this USB (mini-B) cable that forks to a "black" and "red" connection:

[image: USB (mini-B) cable that forks to a "black" and "red" connection]

The cable was included with some product. I'm *pretty* sure it was a camera (which I no longer have and never used). So, my guess was always that you could get faster transfer rate if both the red and black ends are plugged into the laptop. But that sounds crazy. Is that technically possible? If not, why have a forked connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell from that pic, but it looks like it was for an external hard drive bay.  Two USB-A plugs, one for data, one for more power, and mini-B to connect to the hard drive enclosure.

Comment: Interesting. One for power. One for data. That makes sense. I think it actually was for an external hdd. thanks!